# Editing a material when it doesn't exist in the current scene

Tags: interface, shader-nodes

I wanted to add a lamp to my scene. So I created a new scene (call it scene 2), designed a cool lamp using an emission material, and grouped it into a collection. Then I went back to my original scene (scene 1) and added an instance of that collection.

Cool - now I have a lamp in scene 1 and later I can add more of them. However, the lamp is not bright enough. So I would like to edit the material in the node editor, to make it more emissive and maybe fine tune the colour.

I can do that by switching to scene 2, but that's quite inconvenient, because I can't see the effect until I switch back to scene 1.

So my question is, how can I edit the material in the node editor while viewing scene 1? Is there a way?

Comment: Why don't you create your lamp and collection in scene 1?

Comment: @moonboots it just seemed like it would be more convenient to have a fresh scene to work in, without all the clutter of the scene I'm working on.

Comment: You could work with the View Layers instead in order to easily switch from a collection visibility to another?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that scenes are the best way, but if you want to easily switch from a visibility setting to another one, maybe you should use *View Layers* instead, it will allow you to enable or disable the collection(s) you want, depending on your needs:

[image]